# How to locate and copy the Bower local cache on windows

Tags: bower, local, bower-install

I have a build server which has no internet access which I would like to be able to perform a `bower install` upon.

I tried to copy the `c:\users\<TheAccountTheBuildServerRunsAs>\AppData\Local\bower` to my build server (which I have done with the `npm` cache (successfully) but it keeps trying to access the internet:

```
bower ECMDERR       Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads
https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-jj-abrams-resolver.git", 
exit code of #128 fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-jj-abrams-resolver.git/': 
Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT

Additional error details:
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-jj-abrams-resolver.git/': Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT
```

Am I using the wrong process?

As a workaround I've had to check my `bower_components` into source control, but I'd really rather not.

Answer (score 1):

Run bower install --offline. This forces it to only use the cache.